# "A Galois group is a fundamental group"?

Tags: galois-theory

I read [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2791) that "a Galois group is a fundamental group". What does this mean? To every number field is there a topological space whose fundamental group is the Galois group of the polynomial?

Comment: I am not sure, any group is a fundamental group of a CW-complex, so "being a fundamental group" is not an interesting property...

Comment: Perhaps the comment was referring to the algebraic geometry version of the fundamental group?  Check wikipedia for "Etale fundamental group".

Comment: see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/546/galois-groups-vs-fundamental-groups and the Foreword in http://www.renyi.hu/~szamuely/fg.pdf

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That comment refers to the [étale fundamental group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_fundamental_group) of a scheme, which is a more subtle notion than the usual fundamental group. As stated in the comments, a thorough introduction to this point of view can be found in Szamuely's *[Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups](http://books.google.com/books/about/Galois_Groups_and_Fundamental_Groups.html?id=_H7PuKhJHZkC)* (of which [a preliminary version](https://web.archive.org/web/20080418222424/http://www.renyi.hu/%7Eszamuely/fg.pdf) had been made generously freely available by the author).

The basic idea is that one should think of the category of finite extensions of a field $K$ as being analogous to the category of finite coverings of a topological space; the Galois group and fundamental group, respectively, come from trying to understand these categories. This analogy is closest in the case that $K$ is a one-dimensional function field over $\mathbb{C}$; in that case, it turns out that $K$ is the field of meromorphic functions on a [compact Riemann surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface), and that studying finite extensions of $K$ is the same thing as studying (branched) covers of this Riemann surface.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice survey article by Liang Xiao in [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Elxiao/files/notes/Fundamental%20Groups.pdf).