# Is topological Galois theory an active area of research?

Tags: soft-question, galois-theory, research

Is topological Galois theory an active area of research?

P.S. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_Galois_theory

P.P.S. It seems it used to be very active when V. I. Arnold was alive and interested in it.

Comment: By the way: is there any relationship between it and category theory?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670807/applications-of-galois-theory-for-topology

Comment: Why not write Khovanskii and ask him?

Comment: I haven't read his recent book on the subject but I suspect that if there are still open directions of interest, he might have mentioned them there.